# MySql crash issue

Tags: mysql

Edit: When I run mysql without starting the application, it crashes a query that I run form the mysql prompt:

```
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes*1.6/POWER(1024,3)) RIBPS FROM
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

We are getting a mysql crash at one of our customer sites after upgrading to the latest version of our software. The MySQL version is `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.37, for Win64 (x86_64)`.

I think it probably has to do with the fact that it's installed on an underpowered VM and is CPU is at 100% (I've been told, I don't have the specifics).

It only crashes when the software is running, and seems to crash at the same place every time, or at least it shows the same query, which runs when the our software start:

```
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1f8e7dd80a0): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_apps_objectdata ( id BINARY(16) NOT NULL, partition_key INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, angle FLOAT, angle_unit VARCHAR(10), belt_speed FLOAT, belt_speed_unit VARCHAR(10), box_factor FLOAT, controller_id INTEGER(11), facility_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, file_name VARCHAR(255), object_dimensions_unit VARCHAR(16), object_gap_unit VARCHAR(16), object_gap_value FLOAT, object_height FLOAT, object_hostmessage TEXT, object_id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL, object_index INTEGER(11), object_length FLOAT, object_scan_time BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, acquired_time BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, msc_scan_time BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, object_secondary_id VARCHAR(255), object_weight_unit VARCHAR(16), object_weight_value FLOAT, object_width FLOAT, polygon_info longtext, seqnb INTEGER(11), system_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, vcc TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED, increment INTEGER(6) UNSIGNED, device_list CHAR(8), xml_version CHAR(8), token_id VARCHAR(64), carrier_number BIGINT(24) UNSIGNED, inc_start INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED, inc_end INTEGER(11)
Connection ID (thread ID): 16
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

They plan to move it to a more powerful VM, but in the meantime I'm trying to figure out if there are any parameters we can change to get it working again.

The full dump is below. Any ideas are welcome.

```
2022-11-09T17:47:39.776640+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 14795ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=3 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2022-11-09T17:52:59.559921+01:00 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2022-11-09T17:52:59.560012+01:00 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2022-11-09T17:52:59.564490+01:00 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MyApp\MySQL-Server\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.37-log) starting as process 6348 ...
2022-11-09T17:52:59.574002+01:00 0 [Warning] option 'innodb-lru-scan-depth': unsigned value 64 adjusted to 100
2022-11-09T17:52:59.574843+01:00 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Setting innodb_checksums to OFF is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases. You should set innodb_checksum_algorithm=NONE instead.
2022-11-09T17:52:59.575524+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-11-09T17:52:59.575883+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-11-09T17:52:59.576194+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2022-11-09T17:52:59.576547+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-11-09T17:52:59.577347+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-11-09T17:52:59.577768+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2022-11-09T17:52:59.586508+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 5G, instances = 5, chunk size = 128M
2022-11-09T17:52:59.887431+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-11-09T17:52:59.994907+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2022-11-09T17:53:00.056976+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 874257948269
2022-11-09T17:53:00.057608+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 874257948278
2022-11-09T17:53:00.058058+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2022-11-09T17:53:00.058367+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.285223+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-11-09T17:53:08.285762+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-11-09T17:53:08.286822+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-11-09T17:53:08.474153+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.481375+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.482010+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.482753+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-11-09T17:53:08.541421+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 8572ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2022-11-09T17:53:08.541485+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.37 started; log sequence number 874257948278
2022-11-09T17:53:08.543204+01:00 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.546707+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Program Files\MyApp\MySQL Data\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-11-09T17:53:08.564973+01:00 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.565615+01:00 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.566333+01:00 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.566932+01:00 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.570656+01:00 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.571147+01:00 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.572490+01:00 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 8406
2022-11-09T17:53:08.573117+01:00 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2022-11-09T17:53:08.573610+01:00 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2022-11-09T17:53:08.653010+01:00 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2022-11-09T17:53:08.917872+01:00 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2022-11-09T17:53:08.918927+01:00 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MyApp\MySQL-Server\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.37-log'  socket: ''  port: 8406  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2022-11-09T17:53:11.332839+01:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 221109 17:53:11
16:53:15 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=49152
read_buffer_size=2048000
max_used_connections=22
max_threads=500
thread_count=22
connection_count=22
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 3054145 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x1f8e7a499d0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff6bb5e8a3e    mysqld.exe!std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >()[ostream:791]
7ff6bbe4eb89    mysqld.exe!Ha_innopart_share::open_one_table_part()[ha_innopart.cc:200]
7ff6bbe4ee77    mysqld.exe!Ha_innopart_share::open_table_parts()[ha_innopart.cc:337]
7ff6bbe4e232    mysqld.exe!ha_innopart::open()[ha_innopart.cc:1037]
7ff6bb4e79e6    mysqld.exe!handler::ha_open()[handler.cc:2775]
7ff6bb694aea    mysqld.exe!open_table_from_share()[table.cc:3406]
7ff6bb5a9556    mysqld.exe!open_table()[sql_base.cc:3638]
7ff6bb5a861d    mysqld.exe!open_and_process_table()[sql_base.cc:5260]
7ff6bb5aa2d1    mysqld.exe!open_tables()[sql_base.cc:5885]
7ff6bb585537    mysqld.exe!mysql_create_table()[sql_table.cc:5508]
7ff6bb508844    mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:3290]
7ff6bb50b921    mysqld.exe!mysql_parse()[sql_parse.cc:5606]
7ff6bb5048c6    mysqld.exe!dispatch_command()[sql_parse.cc:1496]
7ff6bb50591a    mysqld.exe!do_command()[sql_parse.cc:1034]
7ff6bb4a1e0c    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:313]
7ff6bbf34d92    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2200]
7ff6bbc3ac5c    mysqld.exe!win_thread_start()[my_thread.c:50]
7ffa7e164f6b    MSVCR120.dll!_beginthreadex()
7ffa7e165098    MSVCR120.dll!_endthreadex()
7ffa95fb84d4    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ffa960b1791    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (1f8e7dd80a0): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS system_objectdata ( id BINARY(16) NOT NULL, partition_key INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, angle FLOAT, angle_unit VARCHAR(10), belt_speed FLOAT, belt_speed_unit VARCHAR(10), box_factor FLOAT, controller_id INTEGER(11), facility_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, file_name VARCHAR(255), object_dimensions_unit VARCHAR(16), object_gap_unit VARCHAR(16), object_gap_value FLOAT, object_height FLOAT, object_hostmessage TEXT, object_id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL, object_index INTEGER(11), object_length FLOAT, object_scan_time BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, acquired_time BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, msc_scan_time BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, object_secondary_id VARCHAR(255), object_weight_unit VARCHAR(16), object_weight_value FLOAT, object_width FLOAT, polygon_info longtext, seqnb INTEGER(11), system_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, vcc TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED, increment INTEGER(6) UNSIGNED, device_list CHAR(8), xml_version CHAR(8), token_id VARCHAR(64), carrier_number BIGINT(24) UNSIGNED, inc_start INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED, inc_end INTEGER(11)
Connection ID (thread ID): 16
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: How much RAM is the VM allowed?  Can you get `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the partitioned table?

Comment: I suggest you complete your upgrade to the stronger VM, and also upgrade to the most recent release of MySQL 5.7, then test again.